# Transform a column into multiple columns based on column values in another SQL table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There are 3 tables having relationship like below

Table A

| id | region |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | asia |
| 2 | europe |

Table B (a_id is foreign key referring to Table A id)

| id | a_id | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | india |
| 2 | 1 | china |
| 3 | 1 | japan |
| 4 | 2 | germany |
| 5 | 2 | spain |
| 6 | 2 | denmark |
| 7 | 2 | greece |

Table C (b_id is foreign key referring to Table B id)

| id | b_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | warm |
| 2 | 2 | cool |
| 3 | 3 | cool |
| 4 | 4 | cool |
| 5 | 5 | warm |
| 6 | 6 | cool |
| 7 | 7 | warm |

Now I want to have a view that gives following output:

| region | cool | warm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asia | china,japan | india |
| europe | germany,denmark | spain,greece |

I'm using Postgres database (version 13). Using Python SQLAlchemy ORM to connect to the database.
A sql query would be helpful before I could write an ORM method for this.

I tried to write nested query with joins and case statement but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres, you can combine `string_agg` with `case` expression.

```
select a.region, 
 string_agg((case when c.type = 'cool' then b.country end), ',') as cool_countries, 
 string_agg((case when c.type = 'warm' then b.country end), ',') as warm_countries 
from tableA a
join tableB b
  on a.id = b.a_id
join tableC c
  on b.id = c.b_id
group by a.region;
```

| region | cool_countries | warm_countries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| europe | germany,denmark | spain,greece |
| asia | china,japan | india |

---